PPL equivalent of Task.Yield()?
I am writing a C++20 program using the Parallel Patterns Library, along with their C++20 coroutine compatibility and the co_await and co_return keywords, to achieve task-based parallelism.
I would like to yield the execution of the task to the caller, and resume execution on another thread. With typical task-based programming, I would just co_await another task. However, I understand if the task I'm co_await-ing is already complete, then execution will continue on the calling thread; I would like to manually enforce this yield point.
In C#, there is a Task.Yield() function. I do not see any such equivalent function in the Parallel Patterns Library.
task<void> DoTheThing()
{
    // This portion of the function is invoked by the calling thread

    // I want to return to the calling thread here, and resume execution of the method on the thread pool
    co_await task_yield(); // I'd like a helper function like this, except this function doesn't exist yet

    // This portion of the function should be resumed on the thread pool
}

Using a co_await std::suspend_always{}; does not seem to have the desired effect, either - it permanently suspends the task.
Is there an obvious task yield function that I'm missing? Or is there a simple way to implement one myself?

The solution I landed on looks like the following:
namespace
{
    // ThreadPoolAwaiter is a custom awaiter that:
    // - always suspends the coroutine.
    // - queues the coroutine to be resumed on a thread from the thread pool.
    struct ThreadPoolAwaiter
    {
        // This method checks if the coroutine should be suspended immediately or not.
        // Returning false means the coroutine will always suspend when it reaches this awaiter.
        bool await_ready() const noexcept { return false; }

        // This method is called when the coroutine is suspended.
        // When suspended, create_task is used to queue a lambda function to the thread pool.
        // This lambda function calls handle.resume(), which resumes the coroutine on a thread from the thread pool.
        void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> handle) const
        {
            // Queue the coroutine to the thread pool
            concurrency::create_task([handle]{ handle.resume(); });
        }

        // This method is called when the coroutine resumes. In this case, it does nothing 
        void await_resume() const noexcept {}
    };
}

concurrency::task<void> TaskYield()
{
    // When TaskYield is called, it suspends the coroutine at co_await ThreadPoolAwaiter{}.
    // The coroutine is then resumed on a thread from the thread pool, effectively yielding execution
    // and allowing other tasks to run.
    co_await ThreadPoolAwaiter{};
}

I managed to demonstrate via unit tests the before-and-after behavior of co_await-ing a completed task vs a yielded task.
auto CoAwaitCompletedTask() -> task<pair<thread::id, thread::id>>
{
    auto threadIdBeforeCoAwait = this_thread::get_id();
    co_await task_from_result();
    auto threadIdAfterCoAwait = this_thread::get_id();
    co_return { threadIdBeforeCoAwait, threadIdAfterCoAwait };
}

// This unit test verifies current-state behavior, that the co_await keyword does NOT
// run the continuation on the thread pool, when we co_await a completed task.
TEST(TaskHelpersTests, CoAwait_WhenCalledOnACompletedTask_WillNotRunOnThreadPool)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10'000; i++)
    {
        auto callerThreadId = this_thread::get_id();
        auto beforeAndAfter = CoAwaitCompletedTask().get();
        ASSERT_EQ(callerThreadId, beforeAndAfter.first);
        ASSERT_EQ(beforeAndAfter.first, beforeAndAfter.second);
    }
}

auto CoAwaitTaskYield() -> task<pair<thread::id, thread::id>>
{
    auto threadIdBeforeCoAwait = this_thread::get_id();
    co_await TaskYield();
    auto threadIdAfterCoAwait = this_thread::get_id();
    co_return { threadIdBeforeCoAwait, threadIdAfterCoAwait };
}

TEST(TaskHelpersTests, CoAwait_WhenCalledOnTaskYield_WillResumeOnThreadPool)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10'000; i++)
    {
        auto callerThreadId = this_thread::get_id();
        auto beforeAndAfter = CoAwaitTaskYield().get();
        ASSERT_EQ(callerThreadId, beforeAndAfter.first);
        ASSERT_NE(beforeAndAfter.first, beforeAndAfter.second);   
    }
}

